# How to resolve my OleDbException caused by an INNER JOIN?

Tags: c#, join, inner-join, oledb

Query:

```
com.CommandText = "SELECT questions.qid1, questions.que, ans.1,ans.2,ans.3,ans.4 FROM questions INNER JOIN ans ON questions.qid1 = ans.qid";
```

How can I fix this `INNER JOIN` in MS Access Database?

[image: Error Message]

Comment: What is `ans.1`?  Do you have a table named `ans` with a column named `1`? Or are you trying to refer to a column by its position?

Comment: it is the name of the field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query should fix it :

```
  com.CommandText = " SELECT  k"'.'"qid1, k"'.'"que, k"'.'"1,k"'.'"2,k"'.'"3,k"'.'"4 FROM
    "'('"SELECT * FROM questions INNER JOIN ans ON questions"'.'"qid1 = ans"'.'"qid"')'" k"
```